# Raster Mosaicking GRASS Issue

Tags: grass-gis, mosaic, image-mosaic

I have a project where I have to download DEMs from USGS and mosaic them. So I downloaded them from EarthExplorer and imported them into GRASS.

When I start the GUI version of r.patch using the command console, the raster generated is blank and is not able to show / compute any raster. The GUI based raster query command generates an asterisk `*`.

On linux, I switch to the command window and type the following commands:

```
MAPS=`g.mlist type=rast sep=, pat="map_*"`
g.region rast=$MAPS
r.patch in=$MAPS out=mosaic
```

and owing to the property of the BASH shell, the mosaic happens. However, the Windows version of GRASS does not have any command window (as in MS-Command Prompt Shell). How do I have the same output on Windows? (since the GUI version of r.patch does not seem to work at all).

Comment: I have GRASS 6.4.3 installed with QGIS (via the OSGeo4W installer) and my GRASS version has a command window. For me, the file is located here: _C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\grass64.bat_. Not sure if this will help you or not.

Comment: There is a command line in the graphical user interface (both GRASS GIS 6 and 7 versions): http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxPython-based_GUI_for_GRASS#Command_line

Comment: @markusN: I have specifically asked a MS Windows based question. The link you point to, talks about the command console. I do see a command console, but not a command line (as in MS-DOS Command Prompt Shell).

Comment: This is essentially the same here: you can enter commands in the console.